# Model binding with angular js

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, angularjs

I am trying to do model binding for checkbox using angular js. Checkbox value are binding properly but its not showing as selected even value are true for check box.

Below are the code

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxDontKnowWaistSize" required value="True" ng-value="True" name="ServiceObject.DontKnowWaistSize"  data-ng-model="BodyMassIndexForm.DontKnowWaistSize" class="checkbox"  data-ng-init="BodyMassIndexForm.DontKnowWaistSize=True" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the attribute ng-checked:

Extract from the angular 1.2.1 sourcecode:

```
@description
 * The HTML specification does not require browsers to preserve the values of boolean attributes
 * such as checked. (Their presence means true and their absence means false.)
 * This prevents the Angular compiler from retrieving the binding expression.
 * The `ngChecked` directive solves this problem for the `checked` attribute.
 * @example
    <doc:example>
      <doc:source>
        Check me to check both: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="master"><br/>
        <input id="checkSlave" type="checkbox" ng-checked="master">
```

Comment: did you make any progress?